# A version of Microsoft Visual C++ that does not require administrator rights to download

Tags: c++

I'm using a school computer and I don't have administrator credentials. Is there a Microsoft visual C++ compiler that does not require administrator rights?

Comment: You could get a command line _compiler_ that could be run without admin privileges.

Comment: Do the [Visual C++ build tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) require admin privileges? Otherwise you could follow the suggestions [here](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/02/21/fancy-standalone-visual-c-plus-plus-compiler/) and dissect a Visual Studio installation to extract a standalone compiler.

Comment: For quick playing-around with C++ when I'm away from my PC, http://melpon.org/wandbox is pretty nice. But that's only for gcc and clang, and can't do interactive `cin`.

Comment: cygwin, netbeans, eclipse, clion can all be downloaded onto your desktop and run from there I believe.

Comment: How is this different to "I'm using my ATM to try and withdraw money and it says I don't have enough funds. Is there a way to get money out that does not involve it coming from my account?" :-). The correct thing to do in this case is to talk to your school to resolve the issue, *not* to try to bypass its quite reasonable rules dictating what you are and are not allowed to install.

Comment: to build python package with gcc on windows when doing pip install (without visual C++), you can try :
conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2

Comment: For users having the error in pip install, try installing the binary file of the pip library you want `pip install --only-binary :all: YourPipLibrary`